# The reason to use masking

Tags: c

```
gcc 4.4.1 c89
```

I am using a API that our previous programmer has produced. However, I am a bit confused as to why they do masking in this why.

What is the reason to `OR` the hex with a mask. And what would be the reason to have IPEV_ERROR_MASK OR'ed with IPEV_START. Why not have just the hex values?

```
#define IPEV_MASK               0x9000
#define IPEV_ERROR_MASK     (IPEV_MASK | 0x0800)
#define IPEV_OPEN               (IPEV_MASK | 0x01)
#define IPEV_START              (IPEV_MASK | 0x02)
#define IPEV_MEDIA_FAIL     (IPEV_ERROR_MASK | IPEV_START)
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Where are comments when you need them ;)

Comment: Its all relative but i too will be looking forward to answers here!!

Comment: Could you include any example on how the different masks are used, OR causes the mask to be added to the previous mask but why IPEV_OPEN need to hit IPEV_MASK also is not clear from you example.

Comment: For example IPEV_OPEN will end up 0x09001 which is only logical if 0x01 has another meanin if its not 0x8000 also.

Comment: @Ark. There isn't any comments as to why the masks are set at these specific values. When I first saw them, I was it was just a standard why of doing things.

Comment: @David. The IPEV_x are used for events inside a switch statement. Everything works fine, but I was just interested to know why the masking is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure which part is unclear to you, so I'll explain everything.

First of all, they're obviously bit flags. Bit flags are a way of storing a lot of boolean values inside a single number. For instance, a typical 32-bit integer can store 32 boolean values. This has dual advantages of being very compact in memory, and being able to easily pass around several values at once. The drawback is, of course, that to access a single value you have to mess around with bitwise operators. Thus this approach is typically NOT used when dealing with boolean values in your code, but is often used when storing values or passing them around. Note also that while you physically could mash together every boolean value available, typically you only use this trick to group together related values (like status flags for an object or something).

Now, there are several traditions for working with bit flags. For one, you always define constants with the descriptive names for each bit. Otherwise it would get really awkward really fast. (Hmm... now what did bit 17 mean...)

For another, you always use the `|` operator to join together several flags, even though you could theoretically use the `+` operator. This again has two reasons: one reason is that `|` is faster than `+`, but more importantly, if you were to accidentally include the same flag **twice**, the `|` operator would provide the correct answer, while `+` would mess everything up.

This is a real danger, because in the world of bit flags it is often to see not only constants for each bit, but also constants for common combinations. With the `|` operator you can join these and be sure that the result will contain the bits you want, without worrying if you might have set the same bit twice.

Thus we come to your example:

```
#define IPEV_MASK               0x9000
#define IPEV_ERROR_MASK     (IPEV_MASK | 0x0800)
#define IPEV_OPEN               (IPEV_MASK | 0x01)
#define IPEV_START              (IPEV_MASK | 0x02)
#define IPEV_MEDIA_FAIL     (IPEV_ERROR_MASK | IPEV_START)
```

Apparently we have some kind of "IPEV" bit mask field somewhere, and these are the named constants for its bits. The first constant is `IPEV_MASK`, which sets bits number 15 and 12. Then there is the constant `IPEV_ERROR_MASK`, which includes the IPEV_MASK, and in addition sets the bit 11. And so on and so forth.

The reason they are using these `|` operations to define the constants (instead of simply writing hex literals), is for readability. The compiler will anyway optimize them to fixed values, there won't be any bit calculations at runtime. But this style of writing lets you understand at a glance which constant includes what other constants. And, of course, if you were to ever modify one of them, the changes would automatically reflect where appropriate.

Did this make it clearer? If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to ask!

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a categorization (or grouping) method.  It would seem that all `"IPEV"` values have that 0x9000 included.  The subsequent values certainly could have been defined as a simple hex value, but the method as given is somewhat self-documenting and helps avoid making an error when adding a new value.

One possible use would be that a piece of code could check the IPEV_MASK portion of a value to see if a "code" belongs to that group.

```
if (( someCode & IPEV_MASK ) == IPEV_MASK )
  // do something
```

Comment: Just this. Well, this and that if you ever wanted to change the value of IPEV_MASK for any reason, you only need to edit one line, and not 5 lines. We use similar definitions (and some much more complicated ones) at work.

Comment: @Alastair, thanks for your input. However, the values that are set as the masks, I don't think will ever be changed. However, new events could be added, and old ones could be deleted. And these are used for event handling in side a switch. However, I am wondering if you could possibly explain your idea with an example. Thanks.

Comment: @ant2009:  One example of needing to change them (very possibly not applicable to you, but in a general sense) would be if the masks needed to be changed from 16-bit values to 32-bit values.

Comment: Yes, this seems right - all events have bits 15 and 12 set, all error events also have bit 11 set.  `IPEV_MASK` and `IPEV_ERROR_MASK` seem to be slight misnomers though - I would have called them `IPEV_FLAGS` and `IPEV_ERROR_FLAG` myself.

Answer (score 1):

Masks help you extract the bits you want from an integer, and discard the bits you are not interested in.

The value `0x9000` looks like this in binary:

```
1001 0000 0000 0000
```

So the intention of this mask is to use bits 12 and 15, discarding the rest.

The `IPEV_ERROR_MASK` is a combination of the bits set in `IPEV_MASK` plus the bits set in `0000 1000 0000 0000`. So it could be that bit 11 is reserved for indicating whether an error has occurred, and combining it with `IPEV_START` in `IPEV_MEDIA_FAIL` makes sense.

Comment: Thanks. However, is there any reason in particular you would want to do this?

Comment: I don't know the original context of this code, but seems like the author's intention was to be able to distinguish whether an error has occurred despite of the bits set according to `IPEV_MASK`.